# create dynamically ul & li

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider the following code

```
<div class = 'text-danger'><ul id = 'validation_summary'></ul></div>
```

How can I add values(li) ​​dynamically to ul?
 My incomplete code is as follows:

```
Object.entries(response.errors).forEach(([key,value]) => {
$("validation_summary").innerHTML = ('<li>' + key + ' value +' </li>').appendTo($("div:has(ul)"));
});
```

Comment: Can you show the object that has the response and errors too?

Comment: Yes, I have no problem with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of looping and continuously adding items to the DOM (which is a relatively expensive operation), I suggest you instead build a string of `li` from your `response.errors` object, which you can then add to `#validation_summary`. To build the string, I have used `.reduce()`. I have also used the `.html()` (instead of `.innerHTML`) method to then add the list of items to `#validation_summary`.

See example below:

```js
const response = {
  errors: {
    "key1": "val1",
    "key2": "val2",
    "key3": "val3",
  }
}

const list_items = Object.entries(response.errors)
                         .reduce((acc, [key, value]) => 
                           acc + '<li>' + key + ' ' + value + '</ li>', 
                         '');

$("#validation_summary").html(list_items)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='text-danger'>
  <ul id='validation_summary'></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: tank you but what this : acc

Comment: @farshidazizi it stands for accumulator and is used with the `.reduce()` method. It initially starts as an empty string `''`, and then gets a list item added to it. Then, on the next iteration/loop, `acc` will be equal to the string which contains all the previously added list items (`li`)

Answer (score 0):

Try this example based on your code:

```js
const response = {
  errors: {
    err1: 'error 1',
    err2: 'error 2',
    err3: 'error 3',
  }
}

Object.entries(response.errors).forEach(([key,value]) => {
  $("#validation_summary").innerHTML = $("div:has(ul)").append('<li>' + key + ': ' + value +' </li>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='text-danger'>
  <ul id='validation_summary'></ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class = 'text-danger'><ul id = 'validation_summary'></ul></div>
```

```js
let errors = {one:"test 1",two : "test 2"};

Object.entries(errors).forEach(([key,value]) => {
    $(`<li>${key} -- ${value} </li>`).appendTo("ul#validation_summary");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class = 'text-danger'><ul id='validation_summary'></ul></div>
```

You can just append to your ul while looping through it.